# How to merge groups of arrays?

Tags: ruby

I've got an array which itself contains a number of arrays which again contain a number of arrays like this:

```
array[0] = [["a","b","c"],["d","e","f"]]
array[1] = [["u","v","w"],["x","y","z"]]
```

Now, how do I get to something like this:

```
array = [["a","b","c"],["d","e","f"],["u","v","w"],["x","y","z"]]
```

Answer (score 3):

```
array.flatten(1)
# => [["a", "b", "c"], ["d", "e", "f"], ["u", "v", "w"], ["x", "y", "z"]]
```

[Array#flatten](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Array.html#method-i-flatten) takes an optional argument that limits how many levels of the array will be flattened.

Comment: +1... I tried `array.flatten` only, which led me to wrong direction.

Answer (score 3):

Here's the quickest

```
array.reduce(:+)
# => [["a", "b", "c"], ["d", "e", "f"], ["u", "v", "w"], ["x", "y", "z"]]
```

Comment: `reduce` is an alias for `inject` and has been for a long time.

Comment: @muistooshort thanks, I prefer `reduce` because the name is more telling, but I see that `inject` is much more popular.

Answer (score 1):

`array[0] += array[1]` will let `array[0]` get you:

```
# => [["a", "b", "c"], ["d", "e", "f"], ["u", "v", "w"], ["x", "y", "z"]]
```

`new_array = array[0] + array[1]` will let `new_array` get you:

```
# => [["a", "b", "c"], ["d", "e", "f"], ["u", "v", "w"], ["x", "y", "z"]]
```

`new_array.flatten` gets you:

```
# => ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`#flatten!`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Array.html#method-i-flatten-21) if you want to modify the original array:

```
array.flatten! 1 
array # => [["a", "b", "c"], ["d", "e", "f"], ["u", "v", "w"], ["x", "y", "z"]]
```